# Identify movie: The set is a space crew on a space station and war starts on earth

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

Please help identify this movie/tv show.

All I know about it is detailed below:

- The set is a space station orbiting earth. I think it has a multinational crew. The crew is small (3-7 people, both sexes).
- The space station is more modern/futuristic then current space stations (ISS). It has futuristic like auto open/press to open star trek space doors, a lounge/dining area with a view of earth. Lot's of space. All shiny metalic look. Not like real life space stations.
- There is a scene about wine/alcohol and how it is forbidden, but they make an exception and have a drink But I'm not sure about this clue.
- At the end of an episode/part/preview war starts on earth. Can't remember exactly how this is presented. I think it shows an orbital/space view of explosions (nukes?), but I can't be sure.
- I remember something with Canada or France in the credits or production/distribution company.
- I saw the first few parts (episodes?) of this movie on vimeo (vimeo.com). The other parts were in the making and were not free (had to buy them or subscribe to a service, can't remember)

**Year:** Viewed it after 2013, assume it was new.

I think it was a TV show or a multi series, short series or multi part, etc since it was in parts on Vimeo (I think 7).

Comment: The movie _2010_ includes a small, multinational crew in a futuristic space station. A war does start on earth, and the crew members are told to separate based on their home country. However, there are not many more similarities, and the movie came out in 1984. [Here's the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfxP2Ct9aYs), in case it looks familiar.

Comment: +1 because I remember this, but don't recall the title or exact details.  I want to see the answer!

Answer (score 5):

While I haven't seen the series, I managed to dig up a trailer for [Project-M](https://www.babelfilms.com/portfolio-item/projet-m/?lang=en) on Vimeo, which was produced in 2014 by Montreal-based production company Babel Films:

> In a near future world, stressed by climate changes, energy depletion and social unrest, the Quebec Space Agency has been recruiting astronauts for the Project-M mission. The goal is to prove the feasibility of a long term space travel to Europa, one of Jupiter’s moons. To reproduce these conditions, four human beings are sent into a space station orbiting Earth at 10 000km for a 1000 days. After following a specific routine for 900 days, the astronauts’ day-to-day activities are drastically changed when they prove the existence of freshwater underneath the icy surface of Europa! The 21st century’s most important discovery! But it turns out that not everyone is happy with this situation… What was already a chaotic political situation on Earth quickly escalates into global war. Communications suddenly shut down and the team, forgotten in space, struggles to survive as their time up there is limited. Helpless and fighting for their own survival, they make another discovery that could carry mankind’s last hope.

The trailer is below from Youtube, and can [also be seen on Vimeo.](https://vimeo.com/88389407)

Answer (score 0):

In reading your description, I thought of the TV series *Defying Gravity* but it doesn't fit all of your clues.  It wasn't a space station, it was a space ship, Antares, which, ostensibly was to travel to the other planets in the solar system, but I recall there were a number of shots of the earth as seen from the ship.  The crew had both men and women, there were eight of them, from four countries.  And the show was multinationally produced -- the collaborators included the BBC, Canadian broadcaster CTV, and Fox Television Studios, among others; it was broadcast on ABC in the US in 2009, but canceled before all episodes were aired.  I don't remember anything about war breaking out on earth -- that realy sounds like the movie *2010* to me.

The plot included science fiction, drama, suspense and mystery (there was the mysterious secret about what's in Pod 4).  I'll post some links below.  There is a trailer available from ABC but I didn't include a link because, frankly, the show was much better than the trailer suggests.

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defying_Gravity_(TV_series))

[Defying Gravity DVD Spot - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC9mZjBobBU)

[Defying Gravity Tribute Video Montage - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfxjIeEk3oU)